# How to make Stripe's WebhookEndpoint.create() thread safe

Tags: java, stripe-payments

Stripe's example on how to create a webhook is not safe, it uses a static variable to hold the apiKey.  Does anyone know how to pass the key to Stripe via the builder() method?  Their RequestOptionsBuilder class has the method setApiKey() and I couldn't find anything similar for webhooks.

[Add endpoints with the API](https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks/go-live#add-endpoint-api)

```
// See your keys here: https://dashboard.stripe.com/account/apikeys
Stripe.apiKey = "sk_test_4eC39HqLyjWDarjtT1zdp7dc";

WebhookEndpointCreateParams params =
  WebhookEndpointCreateParams.builder()
    .setUrl("https://example.com/my/webhook/endpoint")
    .addAllEnabledEvent(Arrays.asList(
      WebhookEndpointCreateParams.EnabledEvent.CHARGE__FAILED,
      WebhookEndpointCreateParams.EnabledEvent.CHARGE__SUCCEEDED))
    .build();

WebhookEndpoint endpoint = WebhookEndpoint.create(params);
```

Comment: What is the problem? If all threads only *read*  that API key variable, it's safe. You could wrap it in a `synchronized` method if you feel more secure that way, but I don't see the point.

Comment: Only if the key is always the same.  If multiple accounts are in play, there is a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Per-request Configuration](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-java#per-request-configuration)

There is an overloaded method `WebhookEndpoint.create(PaymentIntentCreateParams createParams, RequestOptions requestOptions)`.
The RequestOptions builder allows you to set various per-request values, including the private key.
I'm posting this as an answer because after weeks searching the Stripe website, it took several emails with Stripe support before they suggested this; so it's not common knowledge even at Stripe.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to pass your secret key via the `builder()` method. The Stripe docs only display the test api key in plain text to make it easier to test out the examples. This allows Stripe to dynamically display your test key in all examples across the docs when you're logged-in to the Stripe dashboard. Stripe's complete integration samples all rely on environment variables to set the API key; which is the correct approach for handling these types of credentials server-side. Here's an example that you can reference:

https://github.com/stripe-samples/checkout-one-time-payments/blob/master/client-and-server/server/java/src/main/java/com/stripe/sample/Server.java#L43-L45

Comment: This example still uses a static object.  We're managing hundreds of accounts so webhooks for two accounts may be modified simultaneously.  If Stripe doesn't have a safe method, we'll have to use a mutex around the section of code.